# JQuery - grab the first round of descendants only

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I've built a JQuery plugin that will apply to a page built in a CMS.

Today the client broke the plugin (which expands a given area based on a click) by adding a `<div>` into the area I've given them access to editing.

The issue with this is that my small JQuery script applies some stuff to:

```
$("div#holders div")
```

My HTML structure is like this:

```
<div id="holders">
    <div>editable area</div>
    <div>editable area</div>
    <div>editable area</div>
    <div>editable area</div>
    <div>editable area</div>
</div>
```

Where `editable area` is a separate area in my CMS of choice that the client can update.

How can I make my JQuery selector above only select the immediate `<div>` descendants of `div#holders` and ignore `<div>`s within those?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#holders > div")
```

See here for more info: http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/

Comment: I stumbled across this and noticd: Note: The `$("> elem", context)` selector will be deprecated in a future release.

Comment: No need for the `div` modifier.  Use this: `$("#holders > div")`

Comment: @MartyWallace I don't think the actual `parent > child` selector is deprecated, but the `$("> child", context)` version is.